# Ember.js Google maps warning persists even though I reverted to previous commit

Tags: google-maps, ember.js

Following this old [deprecated guide](http://blog.atmartin.io/google-maps-integration-ember-cli-edition/), but I realized it was deprecated and reverted to a previous commit, thinking, OK, let's start clean here.

Problem is, even on this old commit, I am seeing this warning:

```
Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
```

/Jackie Chan wwwwww

Comment: Remove `node_modules` and `bower_components` and do `npm install` and `bower install`

Comment: Thanks friend, that solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Gennady Dogaev pointed out in their comment,

removing the `node_modules` and `bower_components` directories and then installing fixed this issue